# Where is ViewBinding GeneratedCode

Tags: android, android-studio, generated-code, android-viewbinding

How/Where Can I find the generated code for ViewBinding?

whenever I try control+click/control+b to see the declaration, AndroidStudio just opens the XML layout.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The generate binding classes reside in `app > build > generated > data_binding_base_class_source_out > debug > your app package > databinding`

A you can see in the following screenshot all my ViewBinding classes for XML layout are inside the above path

[image: Screeen shot of generated classes path]

Comment: @seyedJafari you need to build the project then after that, you will find it there.

Comment: After trying everything I figured it's a problem of AndroidStudio canary4.0
updated to 4.1 and now can find it

Comment: @Somesh Kumar  How do I get to the Android Studio screen you show above?  In the Project section of the Tool Window, when I select "Packages" or "Project Files" I am not able to  see build > generated > etc...  Any thoughts?

Comment: @AJW You need to make sure you can build your project successfully. Go to Build > Rebuild Project.  If it builds successfully you will get the above result ONLY in **Project** view and not in **Packages** or **Project Files**.

Answer (score 4):

1. open terminal
   [image]
2. type `find . -iname "*binding.java"`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Ctrl + Shift + N` (Go to file) to find the file with `BindingImpl` suffix.

Comment: it does not find the file
I have tried all the search options in AS

Comment: Navigation in AS only worked for me after I marked the app/build/generated directory as "Generated sources root" (right click on the directory > Mark directory as...)

Answer (score 0):

The name of the generated class for ***your_layout.xml*** is ***YourLayoutBindingImpl.java***. so you can find the implementation  using *double-shift*.

Comment: I think it's YourLayoutBinding.java. And can not find it in any search option of AndroidStudio

Comment: it is possible to use double-shift. if you can't find it you must rebuild the project

Comment: The double shift won't find the **generated files** in the build folder. It finds only the files that are in the project view. @RaminAbdolmaleki

Answer (score 0):

The name of the generated class for `my_layout.xml` is `MyLayoutBinding.java`. so you can find the implementation in `MyProject/app/build/intermediates/javac/googleDebugStage/classes/you_package/databinding`